# CameraX camera-core:1.0.0-beta01 crashed at Camera2Config.java defaultConfig()

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

Recently, I tried CameraX `camera-core:1.0.0-beta01`.

Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dryeyescreener"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    // If you want to use the CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha08"
    // If you want to use the CameraX Extensions library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha08"
    // If you want to use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
```

Started from this sentence:

```
   cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
```

Then, when I debugged to Camera2Config.java

```
    public CameraXConfig getCameraXConfig() {
        return defaultConfig();
    }
```

It crashed at:
    public static CameraXConfig defaultConfig() {

```
    // Create the camera factory for creating Camera2 camera objects
    CameraFactory.Provider cameraFactoryProvider = Camera2CameraFactory::new;
```

I searched there was an application example by using Kotlin and camera-core beta version without any issue. But the codes, I used the Java version, definitely crashed.

Has anyone implemented the CameraX Java version successfully? Or did I miss something?

Thanks,
Di

Please find the following from Logcat:

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #0 bootstrap method
        at androidx.camera.camera2.Camera2Config.defaultConfig(Camera2Config.java:52)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.Camera2Config$DefaultProvider.getCameraXConfig(Camera2Config.java:88)
        at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.getOrCreateInstance(CameraX.java:823)
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(ProcessCameraProvider.java:103)
        at com.example.screener.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at androidx.camera.camera2.Camera2Config.defaultConfig(Camera2Config.java:52) 
        at androidx.camera.camera2.Camera2Config$DefaultProvider.getCameraXConfig(Camera2Config.java:88) 
        at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.getOrCreateInstance(CameraX.java:823) 
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(ProcessCameraProvider.java:103) 
        at com.example.screener.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:144) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: Could you share the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: Hi Husayn, thanks. Please find the following:

Comment: Hi Husayn, thanks for your reminder. The crashing issue solved.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the crashing issue from requesting Java 8.
Added the following in build.gradle, then the issue was solved.

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```